# Can every open set of a polish space be expressed as a countable union of compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, polish-spaces

> Let $X$ be a polish space and $A \subset X$ be an open subset. Can we find a sequence of compact subsets $(K_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ such that $A= \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_n$?

I read a post where the following conditions were mentioned: *"In fact the statement holds in all hereditarily Lindelöf locally compact Hausdorff spaces..."*.

But there are polish space which are not locally compact. What is the reason for this disparity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C[0,1]$ with the usual sup norm is counter-example. This is Polish and the whole space is an open subset. If it is written as a countable union of compact sets, then Baire Category Theorem  would show that one of those compact sets must have an interior. But this makes the space finite dimensional, a contradiction.

[ If a compact set $K$ contains an interior point then some closed ball of (some postive radius)  is contained in $K$.  By transaltion, this makes the closed ball around $0$ compact. But this cannot happen in an infinite dimensional normed linear space].

$C[0,1]$ can be replaced with any separable infinite dimensional Banach space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just don't understand the last argument: why follows from the fact that one of those compact sets has a non-empty interior that the space is finite-dimensional?

Comment: @JorisWk I have added some details.

Comment: thanks for your help!